# Where do exponent denominators (fractional exponents) in big-O time complexity come from?

Tags: algorithm, big-o, time-complexity

In algorithm descirptions, I sometimes encounter time complexities that look like: *O(n<sup>29/20</sup>+m<sup>7/3</sup>)*. I see where `+` and numerators in powers come from: `+` means successive loops, and numerators mean nested loops. For example this (useless) algorithm has *O(n<sup>2</sup>+m)* time complexity:

```java
public int compute(int n, int m) {
  int answer = 0;
  for (int i=0; i<n; i++) {
    for (int j=0; j<n; j++) {
      answer += i-j;
    }
  }
  for (int i=0; i<m; i++) {
      answer -= i;
  }
  return answer;
}
```

But I don't understand what could introduce the denominators (20 and 3 in the first example).

Comment: O(n^(29/20) + n^7/3) = O(n^7/3)

Comment: @amit You're right, I edited the question. I should have had different parameters to need that addition.

Comment: Do you know where `O(phi^n)` comes from in Fibonacci? Or are you asking specifically when the fraction is in the power, and not the base?

Comment: @amit When the fraction is in the power, and not the base.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

They are coming from strict analysis of the complexity function.

One common example is for [Matrix Multiplication](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_multiplication), while the Naive solution is `O(n^3)` multiply operations, [there are some faster solutions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_multiplication#Algorithms_for_efficient_matrix_multiplication).

One of the first improvements offered to use 7 (instead of 8) multiplications operations to multiply two 2X2 matrices.

If you invoke this recursively for all your submatrices you will see it will require `O(n^log_2(7)) ~= O(n^2.807)` multiplications.

---

Another common example is the [Fibinacci sequence](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fibonacci_number) using a Naive recursive solution:

```
F(x) = x > 2? F(x-1) + F(x-2) : 1
```

While you can definetly analyze it with more relaxed bounds and say that the above is `O(2^n)`, in fact - closer analysis will show you that you only generate `F(x)` stop clauses in order to calculate the value of `F(x)`. 

Since we know F(x) is in `O(Phi^n)`, and using some basic algebra to show that the number of non stop clauses is a constant factor of the number of stop clauses, we can derive that this solution runs in `O(Phi^n)~=O(1.62^n)`, which is a tighter bound.

---

For actual fractions, you can get them as well using root functions, where the most common is the squared root.

For example, the following is a Naive implementation to find if a number `n` is prime or not:

```
for i from 2 to sqrt(n):
    if n % i == 0:
         return false
return true
```

As you can see, the above runs in `O(sqrt(n)) = O(n^(1/2))` time.