# Big O notation for the complexity function of the fourth root of n

Tags: algorithm, math, big-o, time-complexity, complexity-theory

I am expected to find the Big O notation for the following complexity function: `f(n) = n^(1/4)`.

I have come up with a few possible answers.

1. The more accurate answer would seem to be `O(n^1/4)`. However, since it contains a root, it isn't a polynomial, and I've never seen this *n*'th rooted `n` in any textbook or online resource.
2. Using the mathematical definition, I can try to define an upper-bound function with a specified `n` limit. I tried plotting `n^(1/4)` **in red** with `log2 n` **in blue** and `n` **in green**.

[image]

The `log2 n` curve intersects with `n^(1/4)` at `n=2.361` while `n` intersects with `n^(1/4)` at `n=1`.

Given the formal mathematical definition, we can come up with two additional Big O notations with different limits.

The following shows that `O(n)` works for `n > 1`.

```
f(n) is O(g(n))
Find c and n0 so that
n^(1/4) ≤ cn 
where c > 0 and n ≥ n0
C = 1 and n0 = 1
f(n) is O(n) for n > 1
```

This one shows that `O(log2 n)` works for `n > 3`.

```
f(n) is O(g(n))
Find c and n0 so that
n^(1/4) ≤ clog2 n 
where c > 0 and n ≥ n0
C = 1 and n0 = 3
f(n) is O(log2 n) for n > 3
```

**Which Big O description of the complexity function would be typically used? Are all 3 "correct"? Is it up to interpretation?**

Comment: `n^(1/4)` is not `O(log n)`.  They intersect again when `n=2^16`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

- Using `O(n^1/4)` is perfectly fine for big O notation. [Here are some examples of fractures in exponents from real life examples](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28924759/572670)
- O(n) is also correct (because big O giving only upper bound), but it is not *tight*, so `n^1/4` is in `O(n)`, but not in `Theta(n)`
- `n^1/4` is NOT in `O(log(n))` (proof guidelines follows).

---

For any value `r>0`, and for large enough value of `n`, `log(n) < n^r`.

Proof:

Have a look on  `log(log(n))` and `r*log(n)`. The first is clearly smaller than the second for large enough values. In big O notation terminology, we can definetly say that the `r*log(n))` is NOT in `O(log(log(n))`, and `log(log(n))` is<sup>(1)</sup>, so we can say that:

```
log(log(n)) < r*log(n) = log(n^r)     for large enough values of n
```

Now, exponent each side with base of `e`. Note that both left hand and right hand values are positives for large enough `n`:

```
e^log(log(n)) < e^log(n^r)
log(n) < n^r
```

Moreover, with similar way, we can show that for any constant `c`, and for large enough values of `n`:

```
c*log(n) < n^r
```

So, by definition it means `n^r` is NOT in `O(log(n))`, and your specific case: `n^0.25` is NOT in `O(log(n))`.

---

Footnotes:

(1) If you are still unsure, create a new variable `m=log(n)`, is it clear than `r*m` is not in `O(log(m))`? Proving it is easy, if you want an exercise.